# ANTLR match only a specific string within a stream and ignore the rest

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

First of all, i am new to ANTLR. What i am asking may be trivial for the rest of you guys, but i need your help.

I want to match all the qualified names within a stream, and ignore the rest of the characters from the stream.

I tried the following:

```
findAllQualifiedNames
    :   qualifiedName+
    ;

qualifiedName 
    :   IDENTIFIER
        ('.' IDENTIFIER)*
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    :   ('_'
    |   '$'
    |   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'))
        ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '$')*
    ;
AnyOtherChar
    :   . 
    {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

But it doesn't work the way i expected: for the input `a.b.c;d.e.f;`, it matches only `a.b.c` as a qualified name. And i get the error:

> No viable alternative at ;

**EDIT:**

For the grammar above, i tried the following input:
a.b.c;
d.e.f; .. {x.y;}

I expected to match `a.b.c, d.e.f` and `x.y`, but i get the following:

[image: Eclipse plugin interpreter]

Comment: for the input a.b.c;d.e.f; , it matches only a.b.c as a qualified name. And i get the error: No viable alternative at ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it doesn't work the way i expected: for the input a.b.c;d.e.f;, it matches only a.b.c as a qualified name. And i get the error: ...

I cannot reproduce that.

Using the debugger from ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, I get the following parse tree:

[image]

*(as you can see, no error/warning is printed on the output-screen (lower-left corner))*

Of course, you'll need to account for text inside string literals and comments that "look" like qualified names, but I showed that in a [previous Q&A of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878528/replace-token-in-antlr) (I'm posting this last remark more for future readers that might think it's *that* easy to fetch all qualified names from a Java source file).

### EDIT

The fact that `a.b.c; d.e.f; .. {x.y;}` produces error(s) is because the two `.`'s (dots) in there. The dot is being tokenized separately, not as a `AnyOtherChar` token.

Defining literal tokens inside parser rules (like you did with `'.'` in `qualifiedName`) does ***not*** cause these tokens to be created only in those parser rules. The following two grammars are identical:

#### 1

```
qualifiedName : IDENTIFIER ('.' IDENTIFIER)*;
IDENTIFIER    : ('_' | '$' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

#### 2

```
qualifiedName : IDENTIFIER (DOT IDENTIFIER)*;
IDENTIFIER    : ('_' | '$' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
DOT           : '.';
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: ok i got it now. But is there a way to ignore these dots when they're not inside an IDENTIFIER?

Comment: @user1019710, ignore them? If they're there, they must be accounted for, right? Not sure what you expect to happen in such cases...